# Legal situation to bowhunt in Hungary for foreigners

Tags: legality, bow-hunting

As a foreigner from the EU, what prerequisites do I have to fulfill to hunt with a bow in Hungary?

**Edit**:

I'm asking for general rules like "You need an accepted hunting licence. Most of the EU hunting licences - like the German 'Jagdschein' - are accepted." and so on. I **don't** ask for specific hunting seasons like "When and how am I able to go for deer?".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I have found [here](http://vadasz.info.hu/omvk/balesetvedelem.doc) on page 2 is that you are allowed to hunt with gun permit + up-to-date "hunting ticket", or with foreign hunting permit. On page 1 there is reference to a law saying that you may strike with your hunting gun or hunting bow if you clearly identified the game and the strike would not endanger the life of someone. The two may cover the case you are interested in.

[Here](http://www.fsz.bme.hu/mtsz/torveny/vad04.htm) are the laws summarized. It says you need a holding permit for a hunting bow.

[Here](http://www.nimrodhunting.com/hu/a-vadaszat-altalanos-szabalyai) it says that you can hunt with a bow in Hungary, but for big game (deer, wild boar etc.) the bow must be above 222,7 Newton pulling strength + appropriate arrows (whatever that means, I am not aware of the terms, sorry). Also says that crossbows are not allowed.

[Here](http://www.omvk.hu/dokumentum/allami-vadaszvizsga.html) mentions that you need an extra permit for hunting with bow or with hunting birds, above the average hunting permit.

**Disclaimer**: I am not a hunter, I just speak Hungarian. I think the best would be to directly contact some hunting clubs or officials. [Here](http://www.omvk.hu/dokumentum/elerhetosegek.html) are the addresses of the national + district level hunting administration organs. [This](https://www.magyarvadasz.hu/index.php?p=vadasztarsasag) is a list of hunting clubs. If you write them, try several addresses and don't expect a quick answer :) Hungarians (and generally the older people) are not so good English speakers, so it might take a time for them to react or to find someone to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bowhunter and bowhunting trip organiser in Hungary.

You not need a holding permit for a hunting bow. But You need a valid hunting licence for Your home-land and a valid licence for fire weapon or hunting bow or hunting bird or hunting dog (greyhound) and an Invitation letter. It's enough for a Hungarian ticket.

Comment: MIVAT - self promotion is not welcome here, which is why the link has been removed.